# Objects for unordered collections and arrays for ordered collections in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have learned from somewhere that if I have a unordered collection (eg. a list of things to buy) I should use an object literal in Javascript. And if I have an ordered list (eg. a list of things to buy in prioritized order) I should use an array.

Array:

```
priorityList = [
   "computer"
   "mouse"
   "pen"
]
```

My question is how could this be done with an object literal?
And is it correct that I should use objects for unordered lists, or should I use arrays for it as well?

UPDATE to one of the answer:

Choice 1:

```
var things = [
    {"name":"computer","price":300},
    {"name":"mouse","price":20},
];
```

Choice 2:

```
var things = {
    "computer": {
          "price": 300
    },
    "mouse": {
          "price": 20
    }
}
```

Which one should I choose?

UPDATE 2 to one of the answer:

```
var ulist = {
    "bar": {
        "price": 12
    },
    "baz": {
        "price": 12
    },
    "bar": {
        "price": 12
    }
}

for(item in ulist) {
    console.log(item); // bar baz
}

var olist = [
    {"name": "bar"},
    {"name": "baz"},
    {"name": "bar"}
]

console.log(olist[0].name); // bar
console.log(olist[1].name); // baz
console.log(olist[2].name); // bar
```

Here we see that unordered list where all items should be unique is good with Choice 2 cause even if I mistakenly provided multiple unique items it gets only one of them, and it doesn't care about orders.

But in choice 1 even if I have identical items they are treated as separate items and all are printed out. And it also seems that it's ordered cause there is no way to get an item without iterating it with [0], [1], [2] etc.

Does this prove that choice 2 is better for when you want to have unique items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more about the complexity of the data structure. If you have a list of primitive things such as strings, use an array ( whether it's ordered or not ). If you have more complex data structure which requires key/value pairs, use an object literal.

If you are storing metadata, for example:

```
var things = [
    {"name":"computer","price":300},
    {"name":"mouse","price":20},
];
```

An array wouldn't suffice because I have lots of information stored in each object... but I keep them as children of an array. So if you are going to store more information than just the item itself, use object literals.

If you have an associative array-like structure, use an object literal as well:

```
var person = {
     age: 23,
     walk: function(){},
     name: "john"
};
```

Comment: So I shouldn't depend my choice between array and object on whether it's an unordered or ordered list?

Comment: Since you edited, I would go with Choice 1 if you are storing metadata per each item.

Comment: @meder: please have a look at my updated post. which one of them should I choose? what are the differences (advantages/disadvantages) between them?

Comment: In Choice 1 all the items are grouped in the array, easily iteratable. The other one isn't as easy to use. You have to iterate through *every* property of the object, the structure isn't ideal imo. It would make sense if the objects didnt have the same properties.

Comment: @meder: but I figured out that if each item has to be unique then maybe it's better with choice 2 because there will only be one item with that name. If I choose choice 1 I could accidentally have multiple items with the same name, correct?

Comment: Name does not matter. You can have `{name:'john'},{name:'john'}` infinite times in a list.